# calculating median to output similar results to over partition

Tags: postgresql

i have a large table, here is a snippet of how it looks like

```
name class brand rating
12   d     1     3.8 
22   d     1     3.9
33   a     2     1.1
12   d     1     2.3
12   a     3     3.4
44   b     1     9.8
22   c     2     3.0
```

i calculated for the average of the rating doing the below

```
select avg(rating) over(partition by name,class,brand) as avg_rating from df
```

i'm aware that postgres doesn't have a median function but i would like to calculate for that column and have the output in a similar structure to that of my window function for average

in case of even number of rows, i would like the average number between the middle two numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the median, you should use percentile_cont

```
SELECT percentile_cont(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rating) FROM df;
```

Comment: that would give me the median from all the rows in the table. i want to generate the median by different groups

Comment: and with adding group by?

Comment: hmmm that's right... let me try that and join with the avg table ^^